# pythonでopencvをimportしようとするとimportエラーが発生してしまう。

Tags: python, opencv

brewで、opencv2をインストールしたのですが、python上でimportしようとすると、下記エラーが出てしまいます。

ちなみに、私の環境は以下のとおりです：
python version: 3.6.0
Mac OS version: 10.12.3

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError:
dlopen(/Users/togokida/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so,
2): Symbol not found: _PyCObject_Type   Referenced from:
/Users/togokida/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so
Expected in: flat namespace  in
/Users/togokida/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so
```

インストールしたopencvがpythonとうまくリンクできてないのかな…という気はしており、ネットにあるブログを幾つか参考にしてみたものの、うまく行かず…。お力をお借りできれば幸いです。

Comment: `brew install opencv`時に`--with-python3`オプションは付けましたか？

Comment: はい、行っておりますが、同様の症状が出ます…。
お返事、感謝致します。

Comment: pyenvを利用されているようですから [pyenvが壊れた？PYTHONPATHエラーでPython3.xが起動時に2.xのモジュールを参照する件](http://qiita.com/xaskg/items/690ce9048e708de41166) が参考になるかも。

Comment: アドバイスいただきまして、ありがとうございます。anacondaを導入し、そこからcondaで、opencv3を入れられました！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

Macでどのようにするのが良いのか分かりませんが、少なくとも、OpenCVは利用するPythonとリンクする必要があります。
次のような記事もあるようです。私はMac上でビルドしていないので今回のケースの合うのかどうか分かりませんが、参考になりそうかなと思います。

- http://qiita.com/shim0mura/items/b0ec437206ed3d19d878

  > どこかのタイミングでpython2.7のモジュールを読み込むようになってしまっていた。そのため、brewでOpenCVをビルドした時にsoファイルが/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/に置かれたり、ファイルの中でもpython2.7前提でのビルドがされているために、シンボリックリンクを張っても以下のようなエラーが出てpythonで読み込めなかったりした。
- http://qiita.com/xaskg/items/690ce9048e708de41166

  > import sysして調べたパスと、brew doctorして出てきたpython絡みのwarningとを合わせると、次のことがわかります。
  >
  > - Pythonが呼び出しているsite.pyから設定されているパス → 正常
  > - homebrewから設定した($HOME/.pyenv下の)パス → 異常
  >
  > おそらく、homebrewから設定しているパスが2.xのsite-packagesを呼び出しているはずです。
  > このhomebrewで見るパスは、$HOME/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packagesの中のhomebrew.pthというファイルに書かれています。(そしてsite.pyはこのhomebrew.pthを読み込んでいるんでしょう。たぶん。)
  >
  > 中を開けてみると…
  >
  > homebrew.pth
  > import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
  >
  > ビンゴ！！！
  > やっぱりこれでした！！！！
  > この中身をコメントアウトするなり、削除するなりしてあげると…
  > Python復活！！！！

余談ですが、私の場合(OSはCentOS6.6)、Pythonをshared libraryモード (`./configure --enable-shared`)でビルドして、OpenCVはこのPythonを使うようにしました。そのために、ld.so.confにPythonのsoファイルのパスを設定してldconfigしています。
Macで頑張らずにVirtual Machineなどを使って仮想OS上で扱うのもひとつの方法かと思います。

Comment: できればSOの回答は外部リンクに頼らず、なるべくself-containedになっていることが望まれているので、もしよければリンク先の内容も多少回答に含めていただけませんか？  [ヘルプセンター](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)には「重要なリンク先の最も関連性が高い部分を必ず引用してください」とあります。

Comment: アドバイスいただきまして、ありがとうございます！お返事が遅くなり、大変失礼いたしました。anacondaを導入し、そこからconda経由でopencv3がインストールできました。御礼申し上げます。